# Select posts from users which are followed

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent hours and still couldn't able to do it correctly. I have user table, and posts table.

**User table**

```
username | followers        | following

john     | mary,steven,joel | anthony,matthew
```

**Posts table**

```
fromuser | post                    | date 

mary     | Bla bla, today is cold. | 1475982647
```

I need to get posts from the users who are being followed. Tried this;

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE $member[nick] 
IN (SELECT followers FROM users WHERE $member[nick] IN followers ORDER BY id DESC limit 10
```

This doesn't return any posts. What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: don't separate data by comma

Comment: @FastSnail, its just for followers and following rows, since comma is not allowed, I used it once. Are there any problems ?

Comment: @canertaşdemir yes [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(fromuser,
                  (SELECT following FROM users WHERE username = 'john')) > 0
```

This query uses `FIND_IN_SET` to check each user appearing in `posts` whether or not he is being followed by a given user (John in this case).

Comment: @canertaşdemir I updated with logic which will consider either empty string or `NULL` as meaning there are no followers for that user.

Comment: In your query, where should I include the current user ? $member[nick]

Comment: @canertaşdemir Just add an additional check to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So this will get the posts from users which are followed by "John", correct ?

Comment: Your language is _very_ unclear.  Let me update again

Comment: I just want to get posts from users which are being followed, for example, in facebook on homepage, we see posts only from people we follow. I try to explain this.

Comment: I updated again.  Now it finds the posts from users who are _followed_ by John.